# Uniform convergence of $\sum \cos^n x \sin x$ on $[0, \pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I wonder how to check uniform convergence on the closed interval $[0, \pi]$ of the following series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos^n x \sin x $$
I came to consider this through a modification of a simpler example $\sum n\cos^n x \sin x$ where the necessary condition for uniform convergence is not met, i.e. the sequence $n\cos^n x \sin x$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ (as demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91065/does-f-nx-n-cosn-x-sin-x-uniformly-converge-for-x-in-0-frac-pi2)). However, in the modified example, this line of argument does not seem to work. How would you prove/disprove uniform convergence in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute this sum S. 
$$S(0) = S(\pi) = 0$$
And, if $0 <x< \pi$ :

$$S(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos^n(x) \sin(x) = \sin(x) \cos(x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^n(x) = \frac{1}2 \frac{\sin(2x)}{1 - \cos(x)}$$

The last expression diverges when $x \to 0$. Indeed, with $\epsilon_i(x) \to 0$ when $x \to 0$

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{1 - \cos(x)} = \frac{2x + x \epsilon_1(x)}{x^2/2+ x^2 \epsilon_2(x)/2} =  4 \frac{2 + \epsilon_1(x)}{x + x\epsilon_2(x)} \displaystyle\to +\infty \quad [x \to 0^{+}]$$

Thus, there is still a problem at $x = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps an easier end game: Since $S(x)= \dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{1-\cos x},$ we can let $u=\cos x$ and the expression becomes

$$\frac{(1-u^2)^{1/2}u}{1-u} = \frac{(1+u)^{1/2}u}{(1-u)^{1/2}}.$$

This gives $\infty$ for the limit as $x\to 0^+.$